# Does Hy have inline if?

Tags: python, lisp, hy

What is the Hy equivalent of Python's `a if condition else b`?
I'm trying to convert something like this

```py
return (quicksort(under) if under else []) + same + (quicksort(over) if over else [])
```

to Hy. It avoids calling `quicksort()` if the list is empty. I know I can do

```
(if under
   (quicksort under)
   [])
```

but I'd rather have it on one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy is a free-form language (like most programming languages, but unlike Python). You can write `(if under (quicksort under) [])` in one line, like so, and it makes no difference to the parser.

Whether the Hy compiler produces a Python `if` expression or a Python `if` statement for your Hy `if` form is supposed to be an implementation detail that you don't have to worry about.

Comment: forgot about that ‍♂️ "You can take the man out of Python, but you can't take the Python out of the man"

Comment: @Tuor Heh, good one.